# ReactTestUtils Simulate.Change parameter type SyntheticEventData error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-dom, reactjs-testutils

I have this code below written in typescript which use ReactTestUtils from "react-dom/test-utils".

```
let nameInput = TestUtilsExtended.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(root, "input");

TestUtilsExtended.Simulate.change(nameInput, {
    target: {
        value : "alice"
    }
} as any);
```

It works fine and the result is as intended when I put that `as any` casting. If I remove the casting, this error occurs:

> [ts] Argument of type '{ target: { value: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SyntheticEventData'. Types of property 'target' are incompatible. Type '{ value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'EventTarget'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'value' does not exist in type 'EventTarget'.

Here is the intellisense for `Simulate.change` I got from `@types/react-dom (version: ^15.5.4)`:

```
const Simulate.change: (element: React.ReactInstance, eventData?: SyntheticEventData) => void
```

In the declaration of the `SyntheticEventData` interface, I found that the `target` property's type is [Javascript `EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget):

```
export interface OptionalEventProperties {
    // ....
    target?: EventTarget;
}

export interface SyntheticEventData extends OptionalEventProperties {
    // ....
}
```

Since the code works as intended when I put the `as any` casting, I don't quite get how this `EventTarget` interface works.

Do you guys know the workaround to remove the `as any` casting? Because if possible I'd like to minimize casting anything to `any` in my code. I want to make the code strongly typed.

Answer (score 2):

you need to cast as unknown and then cast it to EventTarget

```
let nameInput = TestUtilsExtended.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(root, "input");

TestUtilsExtended.Simulate.change(nameInput, {
    target: {
        value : "alice"
    }
} as unknown as EventTarget);
```